# MERN Stack on a LAMP Droplet (DigitalOcean)

Tags: reactjs, express, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean, mern

I have a MERN application split into:
1. `client` folder : Front-End code (REACT app)
2. `server` folder : API Code (Express, NodeJs)

For some reason, front-end calls the `/api` part of the app, but does not return a response. Is the issue in Apache2 setup? or something in the react app. And how is the link usually done between ExpressJs (Backend) and the ReactJs (Frontend).

Routing is setup through an Apache2 Reverse Proxy

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
  Options -Indexes

  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyPass /api https://example.com:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse /api https://example:3000/
  ProxyPass / https://example.com:7000/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://example:7000/

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Just to clarify in picture of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: I understand from your picture what you're trying to do, however that's just not how the web works. Your front end is simply html, css, and JavaScript files that the client requests from your server and the server sends the files. The browser then reads the files and displays them.  Your React front end doesn't run on a server. Try out my answer.

Comment: I managed to get it to work through modifying Apache2 Proxy to route requests from the domain into two separate paths to a local address:
/api --> localhost:3000
/ --> localhost:7000
The REACT application routes the API calls to the web-accessible backend URL.
Called ```npm start-script build``` and launched the React app
Called ```npm start``` on the expressjs app in order to start up the server
Everything worked afterwards, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you've forgotten to prepare your React App for production.  You spent all the time developing it and using react-scripts-start or something similar.  When you are done developing you have to run react-scripts-build so that your code can be transpiled into something the browser can read.  Web browsers don't read things like import and require.

Here's info on preparing for production (it's very simple)
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build

And here's info on how to integrate it with your back end:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#other-solutions

Essentially:
In your client folder run

```
npm build
```

In your server.js add

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build')
```

Now a client requests your index.html from your back end server and it serves your react app.  Added benefit: no more CORS errors.  Any work-around you did for CORS you should probably take it out.